# Replace OR filtered query in elasticsearch while upgrading to elastic-search 5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to upgrade elastic-search to version 5. Previously I was using elastic-search version 2. I am having hard time converting OR query to bool[:should] query. Here is how my query looks like that was working in ES-2.

```
 query: {:bool=>{ 
      :should=>[
          {:term=>{:user=>{:term=>70890}}},           
          {:term=>{:assignee=>{:term=>70890}}},
          {:term=>{:participant=>{:term=>70890}}}], 
      :minimum_number_should_match=>1,
      :filter=>[{:bool=> {:must_not=>{:exists=>{:field=>:date}}}},
                {:term=>{:deleted=>false}},                 
                {:or=>{:filters=>[
                    {:term=>{:user=>70890}},                     
                    {:term=>{:assignee=>70890}},
                    {:term=>{:private=>false}}
                ]}
                }
      ]
  }}
```

Query:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "term": {
          "user": {
            "term": 70890

        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "assignee": {
            "term": 70890
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "participant": {
            "term": 70890
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
    "filter": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "deleted": false
        }
      },
      {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user": 70890
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "assignee": 70890
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "private": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to replace **{:or=>{:filters}}**. I have tried moving this part in :bool[:should] query but it gives wrong results.

```
    q[:bool][:should] << {term: {user: 70890}}
    q[:bool][:should] << {term: {assignee: 70890}}
    q[:bool][:should] << {term: {private: false}}
    q[:bool][:minimum_should_match] = 1
```

When I change **minimum_should_match=2** it changes results. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you please post the query in elasticsearch dsl format i.e. json instead of language specific code?

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Comment: **I have tried moving this part in :bool[:should] query but it gives wrong results.** Please explain with sample documents. Also share doc which is expected